# Different fundamental matrix from the same projection matrices

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, projection-matrix, perspectivecamera, projective-geometry

I use two projection matrices P1 and P2 (for example I'm using [dinosaur dataset](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data1.html)) and I need to compute the fundamental matrix F.
So I use two Matlab functions:

- Peter Kovesi's function: [www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/Research/MatlabFns/Projective/fundfromcameras.m](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/%7Epk/Research/MatlabFns/Projective/fundfromcameras.m)
- Zisserman: [www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/code/vgg_multiview/vgg_F_from_P.m](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/hzbook/code/vgg_multiview/vgg_F_from_P.m)

These functions should do the same thing, but **I have a different F value**! How it's possible? Which is the right functions?

If two points X1 and X2 are "the same" in two different images, X2^T*F*X1 = 0 ...
So I found two corresponded points from two rotated images (5 degrees) by using SURF, but X2^T*F*X1 is never equal to zero with this two funtcions.
Any ideas?

Instead if I use this function that computes F from matches points:

- ransac fit fundamental matrix by Peter Kovesi: [ransacfitfundmatrix.m](https://web.archive.org/web/20150626155116/http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/%7Epk/Research/MatlabFns/Robust/ransacfitfundmatrix.m)

I have that X2^T*F*X1 = 0 .... Obviously F is different from the two F I had with the other two functions...

Comment: I'm sure that Peter Kovesi's function is right, it functions correctly!

Answer (score 2):

Well for one thing, it's overwhelmingly likely that the points aren't perfectly rotated version of each other.  SURF uses a lot of approximations, bi-linear interpolation and a whole slew of things that break true rotational invariance.  So there might not exist such a fundamental matrix (if there's no linear relationship between the two sets of points.)  Yes, this is true even after you do point matching.

That said, your `X2^T*F*X1` should probably be small if the matching is really good, but I'd be surprise if it's ever exactly zero for any real image.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental matrix is unique only **up to a scale**.

So, even if you have different fundamental matrices, both can be correct for your images.