# How to compute fundamental matrix using a stereo pair?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, projection-matrix, projective-geometry

referring to the question [about fundamental matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161940/different-fundamental-matrix-from-the-same-projection-matrices),If I had a stereo pair (2 jpeg) and I want to apply Peter Kovesi's or Zisserman's function on order to obtain F, how can I retrieve P1 and P2 ? these two matrices are 3x4 matrices from the two images, but I don't know how they are related... is it right if I take a random 3x4 matrix from grayscale first image and the corrispondent 3x4 matrix in the second image obtained from the first one by using some matching technique such as correlation ? and if it is, do you think that a 3x4 matrix is not detailed enought?

Comment: Those 3x4 matrices are projection matrices, not F. F is typically used to retrieve E which is used to rectify a stereo pair or figure out the rotation and translation of the camera up to a scaling factor. You have to tell first what do you want to do, and why you use a stereo pair.

Answer (score 2):

The Computer Vision System Toolbox includes a function [estimateFundamentalMatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimatefundamentalmatrix.html) that does what you need.  Check out this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/stereo-image-rectification.html) of how to estimate the fundamental matrix, and then use it for stereo rectification.

Answer (score 1):

Well, most of your doubts would be clarified once you go through [Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to construct `F` from `C0` and `C1`, you should rather use feature matching between the two images and compute `F` from the matched key points.

You can then set `C0` to be `eye` and compute `C1` from `F`